# No such file or directory discord.py

Tags: ffmpeg, discord.py

I'm making a music command using [this](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/d78c061a4798ae81be9825468fe146be). Whenever I play a command I get {query}: No such file or directory.

My code if you wanna take a look: https://pastebin.com/ejR3qPVZ

```
@commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *, query):
        """Plays a file from the local filesystem"""

        source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(query))
        ctx.voice_client.play(source, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)

        await ctx.send('Now playing: {}'.format(query))
```

My former code that worked: https://pastebin.com/SQFzbSmK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using your command you need to pass a direct link that ends in .mp3: `!play https://examplesong.mp3`

```py
@commands.command()
async def play(self, ctx, *, query):
    """Plays a file from the local filesystem"""
 
    source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(query))
    ctx.voice_client.play(source, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)
 
    await ctx.send('Now playing: {}'.format(query))
```